# Find $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin(x)\ln(x)$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin(x)\ln(x)$

By using l'Hôpital rule: because we will get $0\times\infty$ when we substitute, I rewrote it as:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\dfrac1{\ln(x)}}$$
to get the form $\dfrac 00$

Then I differentiated the numerator and denominator and I got:
$$\dfrac{\cos x}{\dfrac{-1}{x(\ln x)^2}}$$

when substitute in this form I get: $\dfrac{1}{0\times\infty^2}$

Can we have the result $0\times\infty^2=0$? Then the limit will be  $\dfrac10=\infty$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** do you know how to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x\log(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x)}{1/x}
$$
If so, then you can use
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\lim_{x\to0}g(x)
$$
provided the limits on the right hand side exist.

Comment: the first yes, the second i think also yes?

Comment: Then $\sin x \ln x$ as same limit as $x\ln x$. (also, I really wonder why the first move of many seems to use L'Hopital, while much simpler and effective methods like this one work better.)

Comment: @Maher: Try it and then multiply the limits.

Comment: got it. $0$ right?

Comment: Yes, indeed (it goes to $0$).

Comment: @Maher: I was in the middle of typing "Indeed!" and I was interrupted. However, as Clement says, that is correct.

Comment: it's ok !.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, you should keep the logarithm at the numerator:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log x}{1/\sin x}
$$
This is of the form $\infty/\infty$, so we can apply l'Hôpital's theorem:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1/x}{-\cos x/\sin^2x}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{\sin^2x}{x\cos x}
$$
that you should be able to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation can continue.

After you have applied L'H rule once, it suffices to compute 
\begin{align*}
 \lim x \ln ^2 x &=\lim \frac{\ln ^2 x}{\frac{1}{x}} \\
&=\lim \frac{2 \ln x \cdot \frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
&=\lim \frac{2\ln x}{ - \frac{1}{x}} \\
&=0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We can use approximation arguments : when $x$ is small $\sin(x) \approx x$ and any polynomial grows faster than logarithm. Hence $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(x) \ln(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$